# How do you shift Pandas DataFrame with a multiindex?

Tags: python, pandas

With the following DataFrame, how can I shift the "beyer" column based on the index without having Pandas assign the shifted value to a different index value?

```
                  line_date  line_race  beyer
horse                                        
Last Gunfighter  2013-09-28         10     99
Last Gunfighter  2013-08-18         10    102
Last Gunfighter  2013-07-06          8    103
.....
Paynter          2013-09-28         10    103
Paynter          2013-08-31         10     88
Paynter          2013-07-27          8    100
```

`df['beyer'].shift(1)` produces...

```
                  line_date  line_race  beyer  beyer_shifted
horse                                                       
Last Gunfighter  2013-09-28         10     99            NaN
Last Gunfighter  2013-08-18         10    102             99
Last Gunfighter  2013-07-06          8    103            102
.....
Paynter          2013-09-28         10    103             71
Paynter          2013-08-31         10     88            103
Paynter          2013-07-27          8    100             88
```

The problem is that Paynter was given a beyer that Last Gunfighter (his first record) was assigned. Instead I want it to go like this...

```
                  line_date  line_race  beyer  beyer_shifted
horse                                                       
Last Gunfighter  2013-09-28         10     99            NaN
Last Gunfighter  2013-08-18         10    102             99
Last Gunfighter  2013-07-06          8    103            102
.....
Paynter          2013-09-28         10    103            NaN
Paynter          2013-08-31         10     88            103
Paynter          2013-07-27          8    100             88
```

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Use `groupby/shift` to apply the shift to each group individually: (Thanks to Jeff for pointing out this simplification.)

```
In [60]: df['beyer_shifted'] = df.groupby(level=0)['beyer'].shift(1); df
Out[61]: 
                  line_date  line_race  beyer  beyer_shifted
Last Gunfighter  2013-09-28         10     99            NaN
Last Gunfighter  2013-08-18         10    102             99
Last Gunfighter  2013-07-06          8    103            102
Paynter          2013-09-28         10    103            NaN
Paynter          2013-08-31         10     88            103
Paynter          2013-07-27          8    100             88
```

If you have a multiindex, you can group by more than one level by passing a sequence of `ints` or level names to `groupby's` `level` parameter.

Comment: I think we should add this to the cookbook. can you do a PR when u have a chance?

Comment: Why would it throw-up this... ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis

Comment: Certain operations require that there are no duplicate entries in the index. As this error could occur in a variety of ways, it would be helpful if you could provide an example which manifests the problem.

Comment: This example has been added to [the cookbook](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/cookbook.html#grouping).