# Shifted difference between columns respecting grouping

Tags: python, pandas

Say I have two columns in Pandas. I would like to compute the shifted difference between them **respecting group boundaries.**

In other words, assuming that I want `diff = A-B`, **symbolically** I want:

```
df.loc[t,diff] =  df.loc[t+1,A] - df.loc[t,B]
```

`df` can have any type of index (including multi-index)

How can I do this for all rows? The result for `df.loc[-1,diff]` should be `NaN`.

### First attempt:

```
grouped = df.groupby(level='some_level')

for key in grouped.groups.keys():
  this_group                         = grouped.get_group(key)
  this_group['diff'] = this_group['A'].shift() - this_group['B']
```

but I get:

```
/Users/josh/anaconda/envs/py27/bin/ipython:1: SettingWithCopyWarning: A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_index,col_indexer] = value instead
  #!/Users/josh/anaconda/envs/py27/python.app/Contents/MacOS/python
```

### Second attempt:

```
grouped = df.groupby(level='some_group')
diff = grouped['A'].shift() - grouped['B']
```

returns

```
/Users/josh/anaconda/envs/py27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/ops.pyc in wrapper(left, right, name)
    501             if hasattr(lvalues, 'values'):
    502                 lvalues = lvalues.values
--> 503             return left._constructor(wrap_results(na_op(lvalues, rvalues)),
    504                                      index=left.index, name=left.name,
    505                                      dtype=dtype)

NotImplementedError
```

Comment: So you want to calculate the value of A minus previous row value of B?

Comment: I'm just working on trying to get this to work at the moment

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use [`shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.13.1/generated/pandas.Series.shift.html#pandas.Series.shift):

```
df['diff']= df.A.shift() - df.B
```

The default is to shift by 1, see the [online docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.13.1/generated/pandas.Series.shift.html#pandas.Series.shift)

To apply to a groupby then you can do this:

```
df['diff'] = df.groupby('A').shift(1) - df['B']
```

Example:

```
In [48]:

df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,1,1,2,2,3,4,4,5,7], 'B':arange(10)})
print(df)
gp = df.groupby('A')

   A  B
0  1  0
1  1  1
2  1  2
3  2  3
4  2  4
5  3  5
6  4  6
7  4  7
8  5  8
9  7  9

[10 rows x 2 columns]

In [49]:

gp.head(10)

Out[49]:

     A  B
A        
1 0  1  0
  1  1  1
  2  1  2
2 3  2  3
  4  2  4
3 5  3  5
4 6  4  6
  7  4  7
5 8  5  8
7 9  7  9

[10 rows x 2 columns]

In [52]:

gp['A'].shift(1) - df['B']      

Out[52]:

0   NaN
1     0
2    -1
3   NaN
4    -2
5   NaN
6   NaN
7    -3
8   NaN
9   NaN
dtype: float64
```

Comment: Thanks. What if want to apply the result within a group, respecting the boundaries of the group? Sorry for the last minute twist, but it turns out that I need to make sure this happens.

Comment: No difference, still use shift see related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23198053/how-do-you-shift-pandas-dataframe-with-a-multiindex

Comment: I updated the OP with your suggestion. Still no luck.

Comment: I think I need to do: `diff = grouped['A'].shift(1) - grouped['B'].shift(0)`

Comment: Does that work for you?, I don't have a dataset to test this on but I can confirm that it doesn't throw an error, if so I will update my answer

Comment: @user815423426 I just tried on a toy dataset and it does work, the second attempt error you get is a little odd, there is no reason I can understand why that should fail

Comment: Just use `df.B` ungrouped; you're not doing anything to it so it doesn't need to be grouped:  `diff = grouped['A'].shift(1) - df.B`.