# make a shift by index with a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, shift

Is there a pandas way to do that:

```
predicted_sells = []
for row in df.values:
    index_tms = row[0]
    delta = index_tms + timedelta(hours=1)
    try:
        sells_to_predict = df.loc[delta]['cars_sold']
    except KeyError:
        new_element = None
    predicted_sells.append(sells_to_predict)


df['sell_to_predict'] = predicted_sells
```

example explanation:

sell is the number of cars I sold at the time tms. sell_to_predict is the number of cars I sold the hour after. I want to predict that. So I want to build a new column containing at the time tms the number of cars I will sell at the time tms+1h

before my code it looks like that

```
                tms  sell 
2015-11-23 15:00:00     6               
2015-11-23 16:00:00     2               
2015-11-23 17:00:00    10
```

after it looks like that

```
                tms  sell  sell_to_predict
2015-11-23 15:00:00     6                2
2015-11-23 16:00:00     2               10
2015-11-23 17:00:00    10              NaN
```

I create a new column based on a shift of an other column, but that's not a shift in number of columns. That's a shift based on an index (here the index is a timestamp)

Here is an other example, little more complex :

before :

```
            sell  random
store hour              
1     1        1       9
      2        7       7
2     1        4       3
      2        2       3
```

after :

```
            sell  random  predict
store hour              
1     1        1       9        7
      2        7       7      NaN
2     1        4       3        2
      2        2       3      NaN
```

Comment: Can you provide a small example of the dataframe you would like to modify, and an example of what you are hoping to get out? From the example you provided it is unclear what `index_tms` and `['old_column]` actually represent. For instance why would the following not work? `df['new_column'] = df.index + timedelta(hours=1)`

Comment: Imagine I want to predict the number of cars I will sell in one hour. I have in 'old_column' the number of cars I sold at the time I am using as an index.

Then I want to for that precise time the number of cars sold one hour later, thus I want to create a 'new_column' containing the number of cars sold, but one hour later. I will edit my question in order to illustrate that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the answer was to resample so I won't have any hole, and then apply the answer for this question : [How do you shift Pandas DataFrame with a multiindex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23198053/how-do-you-shift-pandas-dataframe-with-a-multiindex)

Answer (score 2):

have you tried `shift`?

e.g.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(list(range(4)))
df.columns = ['sold']
df['predict'] = df.sold.shift(-1)

df
   sold  predict
0     0        1
1     1        2
2     2        3
3     3      NaN
```

Comment: this is not what I want, since it's not based on index comparison. the line before is not always one with an index one hour before.

Moreover, I didn't say that in my question tho, I have one more index (say here the id of the car store), so the line before can reference a sell that happened in an other store.