# Pandas.SHIFT in Multi index frame for temporal dependency

Tags: python, pandas

This is my first post so please be gentle. I have searched across the world wide web looking for a solution but I am yet to find one. The problem i'm trying to solve is as follows:

- I have a dataset, comprised of 500.000+ samples, with 6 features per sample.
- I have put this dataset in a multiindexed Pandas DataFrame

The first level of my dataFrame is the timeseries index, the second level is the ID. It looks as follows

```
Time                           id
2017-03-07 10:06:49.963241984  122.0    -7.024347
                               136.0   -11.664985
                               243.0     1.716150
2017-03-07 10:06:50.003462400  122.0    -7.025922
                               136.0   -11.671526
```

Every timestamp, a number of objects can be seen and are marked by label 'id'. For my application, i want to add a temporal dependency by including information 
that happened 5 seconds ago, i.e. in this example on timestamp 10:06:45. 
But, importantly, i only want to add this information if at that timestamp the object already existed (so if the id is equal).

I wanted to use the function dataframe.shift, as mentioned [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html) and, i want to do it per level, so as indicated by user Unutbu in [How do you shift Pandas DataFrame with a multiindex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23198053/how-do-you-shift-pandas-dataframe-with-a-multiindex)

My question is as follows: 
How do I append extra columns to the original dataframe X with information on what those objects were 5s ago. I would expect something like the following

```
X['x_location_shifted'] = X.groupby(level=1)['x_location'].shift(5*rate)
```

with the rate being 25Hz, ie. we shift 125 "DateTimeIndices", but, only if an object with id='...' exists at that timestamp.

EDIT: 
The timestamps are not synchronized 100%, so the timegap is not always exactly equal to 0.04. Previously, i used np.argmin(np.abs(time-index)) to find the closest index to the stamp.

For example, in my set, at timestamp 2017-03-07 10:36:03.605008640 there is an object with id == 175 and location_x = 54.323.

```
id = 175
X.ix['2017-03-07 10:36:03.605008640', id] = 54.323
```

At timestamp 2017-03-07 10:36:08.604962560 ..... this object with id=175 has a location_x = 67.165955

```
id = 175
old_time = pd.to_datetime('2017-03-07 10:36:03.605008640')
new_time = old_time + pd.Timedelta('5 seconds')

# Finding the new value of location
X.ix[np.argmin(np.abs(new_time - X.index.get_level_values(0))), id]
```

So, finally, at timestep 10:36:08 i want to add the information of timestamp 10:36:03 IF the object already existed at that timestamp.

EDIT2: 
After trying Maarten Fabré's solution, I came up with my own implementation, which you can find below. If anyone can show me a more pythonic way to do this, please let me know.

```
    for current_time in X.index.get_level_values(0)[125:]:
    #only do if there are objects at current time
    if len(X.ix[current_time].index):
        # Calculate past time
        past_time = current_time - pd.Timedelta('5 seconds')
        # Find index in X.index that is closest to this past time
        past_time_index = np.argmin(np.abs(past_time-X.index.get_level_values(0)))
        # translate the index back to a label
        past_time = X.index[past_time_index][0]
        # in that timestep, cycle the objects
        for obj_id in X.ix[current_time].index:
            # Try looking for the value box_center.x of obj obj_id 5s ago
            try:
                X.ix[(current_time, obj_id), 'box_center.x.shifted'] = X.ix[(past_time, obj_id), 'box_center.x']
                X.ix[(current_time, obj_id), 'box_center.y.shifted'] = X.ix[(past_time, obj_id), 'box_center.y']
                X.ix[(current_time, obj_id), 'relative_velocity.x.shifted'] = X.ix[(past_time, obj_id), 'relative_velocity.x']
                X.ix[(current_time, obj_id), 'relative_velocity.y.shifted'] = X.ix[(past_time, obj_id), 'relative_velocity.y']
            # If the key doesnt exist, the object doesn't exist, ergo the field should be np.nan
            except KeyError:
                X.ix[(current_time, obj_id), 'box_center.x.shift'] = np.nan
        print('Timestep {}'.format(current_time))
```

If this is not enough information, please say so and I can add it :)

Cheers and thanks!

Comment: how exact is that 5s difference, because in the example data we see here there is only 0.04s between data. And can you give some sample data for which this 5s gap applies?

Comment: I added the requested info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any of you arriving here with the same question; i managed to solve it in a (minimal) vectorized way, but, it required me to return to a 3d panel.

3 Steps: 
- make into 3D panel
- Add new columns
- Fill those columns

From a multi-index 2d frame it's possible to change it to a pandas.Panel where you convert the 2nd index to one of the axes in the panel.

After this I have a 3D panel with axes [time, objects, parameters]. Then, tranpose the panel to have the PARAMETERS as items, this to add columns to the datapanel. So, tranpose the panel, add the columns, transpose back.

```
dp_new = dp.transpose(2,0,1)
dp_new['shifted_box_center_x']=np.nan
dp_new['shifted_box_center_y']=np.nan
dp_new['shifted_relative_velocity_x']=np.nan
dp_new['shifted_relative_velocity_y']=np.nan
# tranpose them back to their original form
dp_new = dp_new.transpose(1,2,0)
```

Now that we have added the new fields, we can get their names by

```
new_fields = dp_new.minor_axis[-4:]
```

The objective is to add information from 5s ago, if that object existed. Therefore, we cycle the time series from a moment in time which is 5s. In my case, at a rate of 25Hz, this is element 5*rate = 125.

Lets first set the time to start from 5s in the datapanel

```
time = dp_new.items[125:]
```

Then, we iterate an enumerated version of the time. The enumeration will start at 0, which is the index of the datapanel at timestep = 0. The first timestep however is the timestep at time 0+5seconds.

```
time = dp_new.items[125:]
for iloc, ts in enumerate(time):
    # Print progress
    print('{} out of {}'.format(ts, dp.items[-1]) , end="\r", flush=True)

    # Generate new INDEX field, by taking the field ID and dropping the NaN values   
    ids = dp_new.loc[ts].id.dropna().values
    # Drop the nan field from the frame
    dp_new[ts].dropna(thresh=5, inplace=True)
    # save the original indices
    original_index = {'index': dp_new.loc[ts].index, 'id': dp_new.loc[ts].id.values}
    # set the index to field id
    dp_new[ts].set_index(['id'], inplace=True)

    # Check if the vector ids does NOT contain ALL ZEROS 
    if np.any(ids): # Check for all zeros

        df_past = dp_new.iloc[iloc].copy() # SCREENSHOT AT TS=5s --> ILOC = 0
        df_past.dropna(thresh=5, inplace=True) # drop the nan rows
        df_past.set_index(['id'], inplace=True)  # set the index to field ID


        dp_new[ts].loc[original_index['id'], new_fields] = df_past[fields].values
```

This will only fill in fields that have id's ==ids.

This code was able to run on a 300 000 element file in about 5 minutes.

Note: i spent quite some time on this, mainly because of how one indexes a panel. At first , i thought calling the 3 dimensions would work, as stated in pandas help, but it seems that this is not the case. 
dp_new[ts, ids, new_fields] = values does NOT work.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have no gaps in the timestamps, one possible solution might be the following, which creates a new index with shifted timestamps and uses that to get the 5 seconds-ago values for each ID.

```
offset = 5 * rate
# Create a shallow copy of the multiindex levels for modification
modified_levels = list(X.index.levels)
# Shift them
modified_times = pd.Series(modified_levels[0]).shift(offset)
# Fill NaNs with dummy values to avoid duplicates in the new index
modified_times[modified_times.isnull()] = range(sum(modified_times.isnull()))
modified_levels[0] = modified_times
new_index = X.index.set_levels(modified_levels, inplace=False)
X['x_location_shifted'] = X.loc[new_index, 'x_location'].values
```

Comment: I get what you want to do. 

It doesnt really matter whether this data is added at a timedelta of exactly 5s, it can also be 4.995 or 5.005. 

However, I get the following error w.r.t. my index: 
"*** Exception: cannot handle a non-unique multi-index!"

Comment: Which actually makes sense since we're shifting 5s, the final 5s of the dataframe will become Not a Time (NaT) values. Then , we try to localize based on NaT values, that exist many times.

Comment: That seems to be the case, indeed. I added a hackish solution to this by replacing NaNs with unique dummy values.

Comment: I was trying something similar myself. However, it now raises the following error: *** ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index. 
    len(X.index) = 1658551
    len(new_index) = 1658551

Comment: Which again I can clarify on. The number of objects at each timestep is variable and is an element of [0,255] . If the object does not exist at that timestep, there will be less entries, and, this code will not be able to write data to a cell that does not exist. For example

At TimeStep 2000, 4 objects exist; id = (137.0, 187.0, 32.0 , 0.0)
At TimeStep 2000-timeDelta, 2 objects exist; id=(26.0, 36.0) 

Ergo, there needs to be a check if the object exists.. Thanks for all the help so far.

Comment: What specific line produces that error? I don't see how this error can arise since the number of values in the new index is the same as in the original table.

Comment: The last line. I think it has something to do iwth the following:
- imagine a random timestep in which we have 4 objects
- imagine another timestep in which we have 2 objects

if we try to fill in the information of 4 objects in a frame where only 2 objects are present, we need to shift the data, and thus change the index?

Answer (score 0):

If the timestamps are not 100% regular, then you'll either have to round the to the nearest 1/x second, or use a loop

you could use this as a loop

## Data definition

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from io import StringIO

df_str = """
timestamp   id  location
10:00:00.005    1   a
10:00:00.005    2   b
10:00:00.005    3   c
10:00:05.006    2   a
10:00:05.006    3   b
10:00:05.006    4   c"""
df = pd.DataFrame.from_csv(StringIO(df_str), sep='\t').reset_index()

delta = pd.to_timedelta(5, unit='s')
margin = pd.to_timedelta(1/50, unit='s')


df['location_shifted'] = np.nan
```

## Loop over the different id's

```
for label_id in set(df['id']):
    df_id = df[df['id'] == label_id].copy()  # copy to make sure we don't overwrite the original data. Might not be necessary
    df_id['time_shift'] = df['timestamp'] + delta
    for row in df_id.itertuples():
        idx = row.Index
        time_dif = abs(df['timestamp'] - row.time_shift)
        shifted_locs = df_id[time_dif < margin ]
        l = len(shifted_locs)
        if l:
            print(shifted_locs)
            if l == 1:
                idx_shift = shifted_locs.index[0]
            else:
                idx_shift = shifted_locs['time_shift'].idxmin()
            df.loc[idx_shift, 'location_shifted'] = df_id.loc[idx, 'location']
```

## Results

```
     timestamp                  id    location    location_shifted
0    2017-05-09 10:00:00.005    1     a           
1    2017-05-09 10:00:00.005    2     b           
2    2017-05-09 10:00:00.005    3     c           
3    2017-05-09 10:00:05.006    2     a           b
4    2017-05-09 10:00:05.006    3     b           c
5    2017-05-09 10:00:05.006    4     c
```

Comment: Hi Maarten. I tried your solution, as it does seem like a possiblity. However, after over 12hours of processing the script hasn't finished yet. I will most likely change my script to work in the most simple way: cycle all timestamps, look for objects, see if that object exists in the past and copy the data if it does. I added the code to my post .